# Delivery Manager is creating pressure (time to complete given task) on me (fresher) while doing given tasks in very first project

Tags: manager, fresher

I am a new hire (fresher), having joined the company 6 months ago. I am currently working on my very first project after successful training. While working on tasks given by my team lead, the Delivery Manager comes to me for every half an hour and asks about the amount of time I will take to complete the tasks. As a fresher, I can't estimate the amount of work to complete the given task. Now, whenever the Delivery Manager asks, I feel very tensed, feel pressure, and feel personally insecure about why I'm not able to complete these small tasks. Is my thinking wrong, or do all delivery managers create this pressure on freshers like me in any company?

Comment: I've never heard the word "fresher" before. I'm guessing it means that you're new to the company?

Comment: yes, right Mike...my sentence formation is very bad. That's why I edited posted question three times.

Comment: I had a pass at cleaning up your English. Hopefully I did not change the meaning of your question.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth 'Fresher' is a term used, particularly in India, for someone in their first graduate job. There's a definition in the tag wiki. Mouse over the tag to see it.

Comment: Have you talked to YOUR manager? If you can't get your job done because someone is preventing you, your manager should help you correct that.

Answer (score 5):

Having been in that situation many years ago, I can tell you that many people cannot work properly under stress. If a manager comes to you every half hour, then I can tell you that he is absolutely clueless and incompetent as a manager. Don't tell him that, it won't do you any good :-) The secret to your success is to not have the stress.

You are a beginner. You don't know how to make decent estimates (many people with lots of experience don't know, so that's nothing to worry about). The manager should realise that. So when he asks you the next time, think of what is the longest possible time it could take you to finish the task. Add 50%, and that's what you tell him. And the important thing is, don't worry about it. If he asks you again half an hour later, you give the same number. You can't work when you are interrupted every 30 minutes. The number only goes down if you have some time to work without interruption.

Now you can do your job in peace, concentrate on the work, and since you gave the maximum possible time plus some extra as an estimate, you'll finish in the estimated time or quicker and look good.

For your question whether all managers behave like this: It seems obvious that the pressure doesn't help you performing. I'm quite sure you would perform better in a better environment. Since your manager's job isn't to threaten you and put you under pressure but to maximise your performance, he is doing a bad job. So the answer is that bad managers may behave like this, good ones don't.

Answer (score 1):

Well, This is common problem but actually they are not asking you to complete the job in given time, they are taking a general Idea on how much efforts will be required so they can deal it properly.

I have faced this situation many times, as I am mainly in Research and Development Work and do not know how much time it will actually take to finish up some job.

So I give the estimated efforts from my side plus I include that it may vary depending on a particular thing , like if Part A is completed it will take 5 more days to complete Part B, but I cannot tell how much time exactly Part A will take and explain him.

For example you can use, I am pretty good at designing it but I can only decide the perfect design when all things are build up.

Or you can ask for Part A , I need your suggestion/Help rest I can do on my own.

Note: Always be honest and give best possible time plus some extra time because we never know what situation we will face in between and your manager should be well aware of that , If he is trying to give huge responsibility on fresher forcefully ,he is responsible for any loss in project .